# Getting Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: php, json

Trying to display values from database for a specific id using json and php

When I do var dump all correct values are displayed

```
function getItemByID($id) {

    //Connect to database and server
    include ("connect.php") ;   

    if (!$connect) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id ='".$id."'";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1);

    $itemtxt = '[{"id" : '.$rows['id'].',' ;
    $itemtxt = $itemtxt.'"item" : '.$rows['item'].',' ;
    $itemtxt = $itemtxt.'"image" : '.$rows['image'].',' ;
    $itemtxt = $itemtxt.'"descr" : '.$rows['descr'].'}] ,' ;


    $itemtxt = substr($itemtxt, 0, -2) ;

    var_dump($itemtxt);

    return $itemtxt;

}
```

This is where the error gets displayed from on line 10,11,12,13

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    include("library.php");

    $itemtxt = getItemByID($id);
    $itemjson = json_decode($itemtxt);


    echo $itemjson -> id;
    echo $itemjson -> item;
    echo $itemjson -> image;
    echo $itemjson -> descr;

?>
```

Trying to get this data to display on this page but getting "Trying to get property of non object" error.

Comment: what output do you get from `var_dump($itemtxt);`?

Comment: let me get this ... in `getItemByID` you are encoding **(by hand !)**, so you can later decode ?  dont encode by hand btw, `json_decode` has a little sister named `json_encode`.   Better yet, just return your `$rows` variable, skip the encode/decode

Answer (score 0):

The string you are creating is a JSON array. For which your `json_decode` is returning an array. Remove the `[` from the begining and end of you string generation and it should work. So change the below :

```
$itemtxt = '[{"id" : '.$rows['id'].',' ;
$itemtxt = $itemtxt.'"item" : '.$rows['item'].',' ;
$itemtxt = $itemtxt.'"image" : '.$rows['image'].',' ;
$itemtxt = $itemtxt.'"descr" : '.$rows['descr'].'}] ,' ;
```

to

```
$itemtxt = '{"id" : '.$rows['id'].',' ;
$itemtxt = $itemtxt.'"item" : '.$rows['item'].',' ;
$itemtxt = $itemtxt.'"image" : '.$rows['image'].',' ;
$itemtxt = $itemtxt.'"descr" : '.$rows['descr'].'} ,' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just fetch the object from the start:

```
function getItemByID($id,$connect)
{
    if(!$connect)
        return false;
    elseif(!is_numeric($id))
        return false;

    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id ='{$id}'");
    return mysqli_fetch_object($query);
}
```

To use:

```
# Add connection
include("connect.php");
# You should have this bit right on the connect.php so you don't have to
# keep writing it on each page you use the connection
if (!$connect) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}
# Make a check to make sure value is set and is numeric
$id = (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))? $_GET['id'] : false;
# I would include this at the top if it doesn't require $id, it would be cleaner
include("library.php");
# Feed in the connection and ID
$itemtxt = getItemByID($id,$connect);
# Check that it's filled and not empty
if(!empty($itemtxt)) {
    echo $itemtxt->id;
    echo $itemtxt->item;
    echo $itemtxt->image;
    echo $itemtxt->descr;
}
```